# Error while loading libthread_db for cross-platform gdb-multiarch debugging

Tags: linux, gdb

I have a host machine running 64-bit Linux in x86, and a target board running 32-bit Linux in ARM. I am using `gdb-multiarch` on the host machine to debug core dump files generated from a multi-threaded binary running on the target board. The debugging seems to work (at least the basic things such as `bt`, `info threads`, etc).

However, I see warnings related to `libthread_db` on startup. I learned that you can use `set debug libthread-db 1` to get some extra debug message, and this is what I observed:

1. First, I see the `libthread_db` from the host machine is being loaded. This fails due to a version mismatch but that seems completely reasonable in my opinion. After all, why would the `libpthread` from my target board be compatible with the `libthread_db` on my host machine?

```
Trying host libthread_db library: libthread_db.so.1.
Host libthread_db.so.1 resolved to: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1.
td_ta_new failed: versions of libpthread and libthread_db do not match
```

2. Then, I see the `libthread_db` from the target board is being loaded (I have the ARM shared libraries on my host machine). It appears that it failed because `dlopen` is expecting a 64-bit shared library, but this doesn't make sense to me because the core dump is generated from a **32-bit binary**.

```
Trying host libthread_db library: <snipped path>/lib/libthread_db.so.1.
dlopen failed:  <snipped path>/lib/libthread_db.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32.
thread_db_load_search returning 0
```

3. Finally, `gdb-multiarch` complains that thread debugging isn't available.

```
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.
```

**What am I doing wrong that's preventing libthread_db from being loaded properly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong that's preventing libthread_db from being loaded properly?

You aren't doing anything wrong, but you need to have an `x86_64` version of `libthread_db.so.1` which is the same version as GLIBC on your 32-bit ARM target.

Alternatively you could use 32-bit GDB on the host. That GDB would be able to `dlopen` `<snipped path>/lib/libthread_db.so.1`. Since your target is 32-bit, you are not gaining anything by using 64-bit GDB on the host.

**Update:**

> exactly what gdb is using libthread_db.so.1 for?

GDB does not know about internals of `libpthread.so.0`, so it dynamically loads `libthread_db.so.1` and asks *it* to e.g. enumerate threads and tell GDB about them.

Obviously for this dynamic loading (`dlopen`) to work, `libthread_db.so.1` must match GDB bitness and architecture. But in order for `libthread_db` to *know* about internals of `libpthread.so.0`, it must version-match `libpthread.so.0` used by the target.

You might ask: how can `libthread_db` enumerate threads in the target process? Doesn't it need to know memory contents of the inferior (being debugged) process?

Why yes, it does, and it uses GDB to perform inferior reads and writes.

That is, GDB calls into `libthread_db`, which calls back into GDB for low-level inferior memory and register access, then uses the info provided by GDB to construct higher-level concepts (active threads, etc.).

Comment: Could you share some insight on exactly what `gdb` is using `libthread_db.so.1` for? I am still confused why `gdb` would want to use a `x86_64` version of `libthread_db.so.1` when I'm doing cross-platform debugging on an ARM target.

Regardless, I am glad to hear that I'm not doing something terribly wrong in my `gdb` setup!

Comment: One more question about your suggestion to use 32-bit GDB on the x86 host machine.

You mentioned that `libthread_db.so.1` and GDB must match in bitness and architecture. However, my `<snipped path>/lib/libthread_db.so.1` is 32-bit and built for **ARM** (I'm not sure if this detail was clear earlier). Wouldn't this mean there's a mismatch in architecture if I use the 32-bit GDB?

Comment: @KenLin Yes, your `i*86` GDB will not be able to use ARM `libthread_db.so.1`. You need to build a copy which matches target `libpthread.so.0` version, but for the host on which GDB runs.

Comment: I see! I believe the gap in my knowledge was not realizing that GDB can use a **x86** `libthread_db` to _know_ about the internals of an **ARM** `libpthread`, as long as they version-match. (Put differently, there is **no** requirement for `libthread_db` and `libpthread` to match in architecture). Thanks for the help!